# Is it possible to have 2 values for !=?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to here. This is my first post, I'm sorry if I get something wrong, but here is my question; I'm making a game in py3 and I'm unsure on how to get it to exit the loop but have 2 different outcomes. I believe it will be harder to explain than to just show you the code, so here it is:

```
a = 0
start = raw_input("Type c to continue previous game or press n to start a new one!")
while start != (start == "c" and start == "n"):
    print"Try again!"
    start = raw_input("c or n")
if start =="c":
    print "continuing game!"
    balance-=balance
    a-=a
    a+=2
elif start =="n":
    print "Starting new game!"
    a -=a
    a +=1
```

It just continues the loop even when c or n is entered. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd make it `while True`, and then put the logic in question in an `else` clause; that'll always be activated when you have no specific handler for the key in question, so you don't need to keep updating the list when you add other keystrokes elsewhere.

Comment: As an aside, why are you doing `a -=a ;   a +=1` when this is the same as `a=1`?

Comment: That said, you can also write `while not start in ('c', 'n')`; there are more operators than just `!=`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy as strings are already iterable, could you do `while not start in 'cn':` ?

Comment: Surely could, but I'm not sure if it's as readable.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response? They're not even remotely close to being about the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
while (start != "c") and (start != "n"):
```

The error is happening you're actually checking that start is not equal to start being equal to both 'c' and 'n', which will never happen.

**Update**
You can also do what @CharlesDuffy recommends above, which is cleaner:

```
while not start in ('c', 'n'):
```

Comment: `while start not in ('c', 'n')` is even better. or maybe `while start not in 'nc'` which is shorter but not so clear.

Comment: @rolling-stone I get an error using code:     a = 0
    start = raw_input("Type c to continue previous game or press n to start a new one!")
    while not start in ('c', 'n');
        print"Try again!"
        start = raw_input("c or n")
    if start =="c":
        print "continuing game!"
        balance-=balance
        a-=a
        a+=2
    elif start =="n":
        print "Starting new game!"
        a -=a
        a +=1
    and the error is an invalid syntax on the ;

Comment: `while start not in 'nc'` is probably the canonical version.

Comment: Thanks! the while (start != "c") and (start != "n"): works perfectly!

Comment: @EthanL looks like you may be using a semicolon `;` instead of a colon `:`. Just updated that in my answer.